# Как сделать плавное изменение табов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код переключения вкладок, как его чуть видоизменить, чтобы табы переключались плавно(анимацию или задержку добавить). Заранее спасибо.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.s-services__controls_link').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var tabItem = $(this).closest('.s-services__controls_item'),
        tabContentItem = $('.s-services__tab_item'),
        tabItemPosition = tabItem.data('services');

    tabContentItem.filter('.s-services__tab_item-' + tabItemPosition)
      .add(tabItem)
      .addClass('active')
      .siblings()
      .removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: Посмотрите на методы fadein и fadeout в jQuery.

Comment: Я понимаю..просто не до конца понимаю, как их встроить в имеющийся код....Подскажешь.?

Comment: Добавь, пожалуйста, часть верстки чтоб можно было посмотреть что и как сейчас у тебя там меняется.

Comment: С огромным бы удовольствием, но у меня сетка на миксинах sass и сложно будет тут описать. Это по сути обычные табы и на active у них меняется только display: block , хотя можно и с opacity поиграть. Я понимаю что нужно сделать, но не знаю как добавить тот же fadeIn в этот код. Или как добавить туда setTimeout . Подскажешь если можешь?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, надо поменять логику вот тут:

```
   tabContentItem.filter('.s-services__tab_item-' + tabItemPosition)
      .add(tabItem)
      .addClass('active')
      .siblings()
      .removeClass('active');
  });
```

Вместо добавления/удаления класса. На что-то типа такого:
https://codepen.io/Lukyanenko/pen/ZqyNwR?editors=1111

То есть тебе надо или скрыть таб который сейчас отображается. Например отловив его по классу active. Или просто скрыть все, и показать тот который тебе надо. Но так сложно говорить, не видя всей структуры которая у тебя есть.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Вот пример кода быстренько накидал. В целом вроде там структура понятна. Подскажешь что нужно изменить? https://jsfiddle.net/4Lqcb5em/

Comment: Получается сделать что-то подобное, но постоянно возникает какая-то проблема..Получилось вроде сделать, чтобы смена с затуханием происходила, но у активного таба display  становиться не block, а list-item, что рушит всю верстку

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос был решен вот так. https://jsfiddle.net/4Lqcb5em/1/  `Спасибо тем, кот откликнулся.`

Comment: Не успел посмотреть) Отлично что разобрался.